# Channels AVAudioRecorder Swift 3

Tags: swift, audio, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

After searching hard over the internet, I still cant seem to find the answer to such a simple question. I am recording audio with avaudiorecorder and I currently have one channel in my settings for my audio session since my recording is "mono". My settings look like so:

```
try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
try session.setActive(true)
let settings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
    ]
audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFileName, settings: settings)
audioRecorder.delegate = self
audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
```

And all I want to do is the following

```
audioRecorder.averagePower(forChannel: 1)
```

For some reason I always get

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

btw this shows up when using the simulator...even though when I try playing the sound just recorded, it works no problem.

Does anybody know why?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As with indices, the first channel is `0`. Just use:

```
audioRecorder.averagePower(forChannel: 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

You only have one channel

So use this:

```
audioRecorder.updateMeters()
let normalizedValue = pow(10, audioRecorder.averagePower(forChannel: 0) / 20)
```

Comment: The important part here is channel 0